# WP Forms - scrolling issue with elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wpforms

Trying to fix a scrolling issue with wp forms and elementor! I have a sticky form column with a wp form inside. When I scroll down the form duplicates and one stays sticky and the other scrolls? And one know why or have had this issue before?